# Best way to do jquery form validation?

Tags: jquery

Okay, so we have input boxes for the following:

```
firstname, lastname, email, password, city, state, captcha, terms and conditions
```

I've done the validation for all of these input boxes.

This validation is seperate for each ID, and works via `change()`

The e-mail and captcha use ajax, and if they are successful, it returns true.

I also have all of the validation inside the form `submit()`

But when the form is submitted, the validation on the ajax takes place again and the form is submitted WHILE the ajax request is processing.

How would I make the form delay submitting until the validation has ran and then auto submit? Like a sort of delay feature?

Each part of validation returns a var named `error` - error can either be `true` or `false`

If the error is false, it prevents form submit by returning false.

I've been thinking of scrapping the whole `submit()` validation, as its just a duplicate validation running on submit and basically running in a loop, and I was thinking of disabling the submit button with jquery unless everything is validated via `change()`?

Comment: why dont you checkout the jquery validation plugin.

Comment: Because I'm new to jquery and I'd rather learn it than use a prebuild library.

Comment: Nice though.But then jquery itself is a library, so you should rather work with javascript then??Plugins are an integral part of jquery, and they make your work easier, doesnt it sound analogous to jquery making your work easier??

Comment: be careful when using javascript for form validation. a user can easily turn off their javascript.

Comment: @jbabey - we use CSS to show an error message if the user has javascript disabled and the form isn't showed. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2):

Code excerpts would be handy but I'd say make your AJAX oncomplete function call your submit. Since you have multiple AJAX functions going on you may need to daisy chain them, i.e. when one finishes call the next and so on until the final one finishes and you call the submit function. Otherwise try having the AJAX only called once after field blur and not again on submit? Again, need to see code to understand what's really going on.

Comment: +1 The async part of ajax is allowing submit to continue. Use synchronous ajax, or to maintain concurrency, consider using a counter of in-flight requests and issue the real submit in the completion handler if you reach 0.